# Pass a variable to sleep in vimscript

Tags: vim

I've been using vim for too many years to count, but I never have really learned vimscript very well. I'm trying now.

Anyway, I would like to pass a variable amount of time to the sleep function. I also want to manipulate that value before I pass it along. Here's a simple example.

```
function! wait(mil)
    let timetowait = mil . "m"
    sleep timetowait
endfunction
```

Even if I try prefixing timetowait with l: it says, "Invalid argument: l:timetowait".

What's the right way of passing the value of a variable to sleep?

Comment: Vim is asynch. Not sure how much use this would be to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- Your method should start with a capitalized name
- You need to access your argument with `a:`
- You have to have a space between the time to sleep and `m`
- You have to execute the sleep indirectly using `execute`

Here's an example on how one could do this:

```
function! Wait(mil)
    let timetowait = a:mil . " m"
    exe 'sleep '.timetowait
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like it works without the space between the number and the 'm', but the calling of execute is exactly what I needed. (My bad example missed the `a:` and capitalized name, but I have those locally.)

Answer (score 3):

Daan's answer is correct; here's some more background info:

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. +1